# Библиотека регулярных выражений

Tags: c++, linux, windows, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача реализовать функционал mod_rewrite из Apache. Подскажите библиотеку для реализации регулярных выражений.

При поиске находится pcre. Вроде то, что надо, однако, тогда встает вопрос, а как его собрать под винду? Желательно без использования cygwin. Есть возможность собрать библиотеку для windows в линуксе?

Comment: По Windows лежат уже собранные библиотеки. Ссылка на главной странице сайта.

Comment: А можно эту ссылку?

Comment: http://www.pcre.org/, крутить до Contributed Ports, там их две.

Comment: По первой файлы из 2007 года, по второй только бинарники, без библиотек. Итого ничего.

Comment: А в чём проблема собрать? cygwin/msys встают же без проблем.

Comment: Я же просил без cygwin. ) msys поставил, разбираюсь. Судя по началу работы собрать будет та еще проблема.

Comment: "Без cygwin" - это какое-то  очень уж искусственное ограничение. Просто любопытны его причины :)

Comment: У меня не самые лучшие воспоминания о нем, хотя, возможно сейчас cygwin работает лучше.

Comment: ЭЭЭЭ а в чем проблема собрать pcre под винду, cmake-gui и вперед, собирал студией

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярные выражения входят в стандарт C++11, т.е. доступны "из коробки" в любом компиляторе С++, его поддерживающем. Необходимости в отдельных библиотеках в принципе нет.

```
#include <regex>
```

C++ reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: Вот блин, все уже есть, а я тут ерундой занимаюсь.

Comment: C++11 не так давно все стали поддерживать. К тому же PCRE существенно быстрее чем <regex>

Comment: Поспорю про недавно, MSVS 2010 поддерживает регулярные выражения, g++ думаю тоже.  Пока выражения будут использоваться для поиска совпадений в ссылках(типа mod_rewrite), не думаю, что скорость работы будет заметно различаться.

Comment: Я передумал, как только стандартные регекспы обратились к malloc() 10 раз, а в тестовом примере 70 раз. pcre вызвал malloc() лишь один раз. Разница очевидна.

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться [msys2](http://msys2.github.io/). Доступна, правда, только восьмая версия **pcre**, но зато и собирать не надо:

[image: pcre в msys2]

Десятая версия (возможно, что и ранние тоже) поддерживает сборку через [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/download/), что позволяет, указав компилятор (его, кстати, тоже через **msys2** можно поставить) в графическом конфигураторе **cmake-gui**, получить нужный вариант библиотеки, не заморачиваясь с консолью.

Но конечно это всё если не устраивает уже готовый набор [седьмой версии](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pcre.htm).

Comment: Msys  с последнего запуска стал круче. Однако в остальном какая-то печаль.

Comment: Как установить automake? Перепробовал кучу вариантов типа pacman -Q msys/automake , не выходит.

Comment: Разобрался, правильный флаг -S.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) она реализует PCRE.

Comment: Можешь, но не стоит. ) Попадать в зависимость от boost ради регулярных выражений не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: Почему же, не только ради них :)